# Deploying Azure Firewall IP Group changes fails with conflict

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-rm-template

I am attempting to deploy an Azure Firewall with a Policy, a Rule and a set of IPGroups.  When I deploy the ARM templates to start everything works.. Later If I want to change something in one of the IPGroups, and I try to deploy that IPGroup change, the Azure Deployment fails with a Status: Conflict with message:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
        "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."
    }
}
```

I've attempted to both manage the IPGroups distinctly in their own ARM Template, and place them in with the Azure Policy Rule Collection ARM Template with a DependsOn to see if deploying them all together would help, but either way we just get "Conflict".. I Guess I am wondering what is the appropriate way to update an IPGroup that is a part of a Firewall Network rule? If I can't simply update the IPGroup?

Here is an example of my full ARM Template for my Policy with the IPGroups..

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "firewallPolicyName": {
            "defaultValue": "[concat('onelucki-fw-parent-policy', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "DevSubnets": {
            "defaultValue": "DevSubnets",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "AzureSubnets": {
            "defaultValue": "AzureSubnets",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "fwPolicyName": "[parameters('firewallPolicyName')]"
    },
    "resources": [
          {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/ipGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "AzureSubnets",
            "location": "centralus",
            "tags": { "Zone": "MixedZones" },
            "properties": {
                "ipAddresses": [
                    "10.99.1.1"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/ipGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "DevSubnets",
            "location": "centralus",
            "tags": { "Zone": "Dev" },
            "properties": {
                "ipAddresses": [
                    "10.99.2.2"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "name": "[parameters('firewallPolicyName')]",
            "location": "centralus",
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "tier": "Standard"
                },
                "threatIntelMode": "Alert"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/ruleCollectionGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('firewallPolicyName'), '/DefaultNetworkRuleCollectionGroup')]",
            "location": "westus",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/ipGroups', parameters('AzureSubnets'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/ipGroups', parameters('DevSubnets'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies', parameters('firewallPolicyName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "priority": 200,
                "ruleCollections": [
                    {
                        "ruleCollectionType": "FirewallPolicyFilterRuleCollection",
                        "action": {
                            "type": "Allow"
                        },
                        "rules": [
                            {
                                "ruleType": "NetworkRule",
                                "name": "DemoRule",
                                "ipProtocols": [
                                    "TCP"
                                ],
                                "sourceAddresses": [],
                                "sourceIpGroups": [
                                    "/subscriptions/<subscriptionIDHere>/resourceGroups/onelucki-fw/providers/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups/DevSubnets"
                                ],
                                "destinationAddresses": [],
                                "destinationIpGroups": [
                                     "/subscriptions/<subscriptionIDHere>/resourceGroups/onelucki-fw/providers/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups/AzureSubnets"
                                ],
                                "destinationFqdns": [],
                                "destinationPorts": [
                                    "135",
                                    "445"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "DemoDeployRuleCollection",
                        "priority": 1300
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IP groups need to be deployed one at a time. Also the firewall policy needs a depends on the IP groups being used despite it not having them listed.

The deploy of the IP groups seems to do some validation/update on the firewall policy during deploy.

[Deploy nested resources in Azure using DependsOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/resource-dependency)

Comment: I am attempting to deploy the IP Groups individually, as that will help us manage them more easily.  They just fail when doing so.  Attempting to put "DependsOn" on in the Policy template was actually one of the first things I went to.. however when the IPGroups are not listed in the ARM template but are identified in the DependsOn, the ARM template fails as because they are not defined there.   I am currently trying to write Powershell to get me past this issue as it seems I can update the IPGroup through Powershell when I can't update through the arm template

Comment: Yeah. I had an issue the other day where it wouldn't deploy an IP group in the template despite there being no changes. Also a test deploy worked and the prod deploy failed. Had to delete a rule in the policy referencing the IP group for it to deploy. Seemed an IP group linked to two policies caused issues maybe. Considering using PowerShell myself for IP groups.

Comment: Yeah, I've got a Powershell update process working successfully for now.   I can update things like IP Addresses and Tags on the IPGroups regardless of if the IPGroup is referenced in a Firewall Policy Rule.  I've been able to successfully update the IPGroup in our "Test" firewall setup, but haven't pushed changes to Production just yet, there has been a question about changes to IPGroups made this way actually updating the behavior of the Firewall and rule based on new IP Addresses in the IPGroup for example, will be trying that coming up shortly though

Comment: Adding the `DependsOn` worked in my case. I initially deployed 19 IP Groups in parallel using a loop without any problem. The deployment had run several times over the months without error. Then I added two new IP Groups with over 4000 IPs each. The error started occurring immediately. Once I switched to deploying them serially, the error stopped occurring.